# How could I know if an object is derived from a specific generic class?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Suppose that I have an object then how could I know if the object is derived from a specific generic class. For example:

```
public class GenericClass<T> 
{
}    

public bool IsDeriveFrom(object o)
{
    return o.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(GenericClass)); //will throw exception here
}
```

please notice that the code above will throw an exception. The type of the generic class cannot be retrieved directly because there is no type for a generic class without a type parameter provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your should do something like this:

```
    public class GenericClass<T>
    {
    }

    public class GenericClassInherited<T> : GenericClass<T>
    {
    }


    public static bool IsDeriveFrom(object o)
    {
        return o.GetType().BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(GenericClass<>);
    }
```

Example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var generic = new GenericClassInherited<int>();
        var isTrue = IsDeriveFrom(generic);
    }
```

Comment: That can throw so many exceptions when there isn't a base type, or there isn't a generic type definition, and it fails when `Bar : Foo : GenericFoo<int>` and on and on.

Comment: I know but in anyway it work for above example. And @Edison can add exceptions handling himself. It just an idea.

Comment: I've tried the example code and added some exceptions handle code. It's work perfectly now. Other answers here also gave me some helpful information but I don't know why I can't vote up to those useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool IsDerivedFrom(Type type, Type genericBaseTypeDefinition) {
    Contract.Requires(type != null);
    Contract.Requires(genericBaseTypeDefinition != null);
    Contract.Requires(genericBaseTypeDefinition.IsGenericBaseTypeDefinition);
    Type baseType = type.BaseType;
    if (baseType == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (baseType.IsGenericType) {
        Type generic = baseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        if (generic == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return generic == genericBaseTypeDefinition;
    }

    return IsDerivedFrom(baseType, genericBaseTypeDefinition);
}
```

Usage:

```
bool derived = IsDerivedFrom(typeof(Foo), typeof(GenericFoo<>));
```

These tests pass:

```
class GenericFoo<T> { }
class DerivedGenericFoo<T> : GenericFoo<T> { }
class Foo : GenericFoo<int> { }
class Bar : Foo { }
class Animal { }

[Fact]
public void DerivedGenericFoo_derives_from_open_GenericFoo() {
    Assert.Equal(
        true,
        IsDerivedFrom(
            typeof(DerivedGenericFoo<int>),
            typeof(GenericFoo<>)
        )
    );
}

[Fact]
public void Foo_derives_from_open_GenericFoo() {
    Assert.Equal(true, IsDerivedFrom(typeof(Foo), typeof(GenericFoo<>)));
}

[Fact]
public void Bar_derives_from_open_GenericFoo() {
    Assert.Equal(true, IsDerivedFrom(typeof(Bar), typeof(GenericFoo<>)));
}

[Fact]
public void Animal_does_not_derive_from_open_GenericFoo() {
    Assert.Equal(false, IsDerivedFrom(typeof(Animal), typeof(GenericFoo<>)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is `Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition`. Here's a complete example:

```
class Generic<T> { }

class Derived<T> : Generic<T> { }
class NonDerived<T> { }

class Program
{
    static bool IsDerivedFromGenericT(Type type)
    {
        if (!type.IsGenericType)
            return false;
        if (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Generic<>))
            return true;
        if (type.BaseType == null)
            return false;
        return IsDerivedFromGenericT(type.BaseType);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var b1 = IsDerivedFromGenericT(new Derived<int>().GetType()); // true
        var b2 = IsDerivedFromGenericT(new Derived<string>().GetType()); // true
        var b3 = IsDerivedFromGenericT(new NonDerived<string>().GetType()); // false
    }
}
```

Comment: definitely, this seems a better example